# ComboBox SAME item selected action listener

Tags: java, events, combobox, javafx, javafx-8

A combo box will fire an event if a DIFFERENT value is selected. I want to be also be able to listen to the SAME item being selected (that is, valueProperty has no change). There seems to be no way to do this.

I tried extending the ComboBox and finding a way to listen for the little popup menu being closed, but I don't even have access to that! What can I do?

Here is what I was trying:

```
class ResponsiveComboBox<E> extends ComboBox<E> {

    public ResponsiveComboBox() {
        super();
        assert getContextMenu() != null; //Asssertion failed!
        this.getContextMenu().setOnHiding((WindowEvent event) -> {
            fireEvent(new ActionEvent());
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
comboBox.showingProperty().addListener((obs, wasShowing, isShowing) -> {
    if (! isShowing) {
        System.out.println("Combo box popup hidden");
    }
});
```

This event handler might be triggered before the value is changed.

Comment: Wonderful! It also takes care of onCancelEdit for me at the same time. Thanks again.