# JavaFX : Trigger event on select already selected combobox value

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I created one app using JavaFX. When user select any value from Combobox(Dropdown), login popup will display. and on that login window there are two options Login and Cancel.

So the problem is when a user selects any value from the dropdown, login popup will appear. Now user cancels login popup.
If a user wants to open login for the same value selected in dropdown he/she needs to select another value cancel login and select again previous value.

If the user clicks on the dropdown and selects same value event won't trigger.

My code is like following

**FXML element**

```
<ComboBox fx:id="userComboBox" onAction="#onUserUpdate" promptText="Select User"/>
```

**Method execute on event trigger**

```
@FXML
public void onUserUpdate() {
    //Displaying login popup
}
```

So I want to trigger the event on select value from the Combobox no matter user is selecting the same value or different value.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can the clearing the selected item of the combobox when the user chooses "Cancel" from popup, be an option?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ComboBox SAME item selected action listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704312/combobox-same-item-selected-action-listener)

Comment: Thanks @uluk-biy reset the Combobox on click on 'Cancel' is the better solution.
And another question is duplicate but it's not solving my problem because It is also triggering event When I click on the Combobox and click outside without select any value.

Comment: I see. So let it stay as "possible dub" ;).

Comment: It sounds like a [`MenuButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuButton.html) might be more appropriate than a `ComboBox` here. A `MenuButton` will display a `ContextMenu` when pressed, showing a collection of `MenuItem`s. You can register handlers for each menu item which will be triggered when the menu item is selected, regardless of previous selection.

Comment: @James_D Thanks :) Yes It can also solve my problem. But I already solved my problem. Reset combobox value on close popup because it fits better with my requirement.