# Can JavaFX ComboBox fire events when selection not changed?

Tags: javafx, combobox

I'm new to JavaFX. Unlike Swing, JavaFX's combo box's action event seems to be fired when the selection actually changed. In Swing, you can add an ActionListener on a JComboBox and it will fire an event whenever you make a selction (by clicking on one of the choices in the combo box), regardless of if the selected value actually changed. Can we achieve the same behavior in JavaFX? Some code below. What I want is to select "Hello" and have it printed, and select "Hello" again and have it printed again.

```
public class ComboBoxSelection extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        VBox layout = new VBox();
        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        comboBox.getItems().addAll("Hello", "World");
        comboBox.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println("Selected " + comboBox.getValue()));
        layout.getChildren().addAll(comboBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I noticed a thread here: [ComboBox SAME item selected action listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704312/combobox-same-item-selected-action-listener). This almost gives me what I want, except this fires when the selection cancels (press Esc) as well. Is there any other solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: wondering why? Nothing changed ... what exactly do you mean by _make a selection_?

Comment: @kleopatra By making a selection I meant clicked on one of the choices in the combo box. For example, if the combo box has a list of dishes, and I want to click on one of them to add it to the meal order. After I added "Burger", I want to add "Burger" again by clicking on that choice again.